# How to install a full geth node on Mac

Tags: go-ethereum

I require to install a full go-ethereum geth node on a mac.
I've found countless of guides saying to just do:

```
brew tap ethereum/ethereum
brew install ethereum
```

But none of them write specifically if these commands will install the full node with several dozens of GB's of transactions or not.

Question:
Are these two commands enough to get a full node which is browsable through the geth command line? If not how to browse a full node?